# django - UpdateView - how to affect different table

Tags: django, overloading, overriding, django-class-based-views

I'm having a problem which I can't solve by myself :(
Lets say I have three tables:
1) assemblies, which holds only names

```
|id|assembly_name|
------------------    
| 1|assembly_1   |
| 2|assembly_2   |
| 3|assembly_3   |
```

2) percentage of completion of assembly with task number (which is added manually)

```
|id|assembly_id|percentage|current_task|
----------------------------------------
| 1|          1|       100|1232131     |
| 2|          1|        90|12131       |
| 3|          2|        80|1131        |
| 4|          3|        50|12241       |
```

3)store - tells me how many of assmeblies i have on shelf

```
|id|assembly_id|qty|
--------------------
| 1|          1|  1|
| 2|          2|  0|
| 3|          3|  0|
```

Now on my index page I have a table which shows me 2nd table, excluding 100% ready. The thing is, i would like to, using updateView, set percentage of given task (i can do that), but i would like also to automatically add qty in 3 table when some assembly reach 100%. Is that possible ? Can I override updateView method, import model store and add something like: if instance.percentage == 100% add 1 to store.qty for given assembly_id ?
What i mean is : after update table2 (id=2) to 100% the qty in table 3 would rise to 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, override `form_valid(self, form)` in your `UpdateView`.
You could save the model and get the instance `instance = form.save()` and then ask what you want `if instance.percentage == 100` and then do what you want. Just dont forget to `return super(YourUpdateViewClass, self).form_valid(form)`.

On a side note, if you don't require the instance to be saved in database before asking for percentage, you could use `instance=form.save(commit=False)`, which will get you the instance before is saved in database. Calling the `super` method will do that, so you could potentially save yourself a duplicated update query.

**Edit:** Example of how it would look like:

```
class CustomUpdateView(UpdateView):
    ...
    ...
    def form_valid(self, form):
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        # The previous line will return the instance, but won't
        # save it in database yet
        if instance.percentage == 100:
            ...do whatever other thing you want to do...
            # Here you can query other models and save them
            # as you stated in your question
        # And you finally return the inherited implementation
        # of form_valid, which will save the instance in
        # database and redirect to success_url (default behaviour)
        return super(CustomUpdateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Comment: So how would my overriden method look like :

    def form_valid(self, form):
        if form.percentage == 1:
            store.qty[id]+=1
    return super(MyUpdateViewClass, self).form_valid(form)

? Unfortunatelly i get global name form is not defined :(